# ChartLegends only displays the last two legends in the list

Tags: legending, plotting

I would like to add 4 legends on a simple bar chart below, but only the last 2 legends appear on the graph.

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {3, 1, 2, 5}, {5, 2, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 1, 3}}, 
ChartLegends -> {Placed[SwatchLegend[{Black}, {"Show"}], {0.2, 0.2}],
Placed[SwatchLegend[{Red}, {"me"}], {0.4, 0.4}],
Placed[SwatchLegend[{Pink}, {"Hello"}], {0.8, 0.8}],
Placed[SwatchLegend[{Green}, {"World"}], {0.9, 0.9}]}]
```

Above is the break down version, initial command is like this, neither one works:

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {3, 1, 2, 5}, {5, 2, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 1, 3}},
ChartLegends -> MapThread[Placed[SwatchLegend[{#1}, {#2}], #3] &,
{{Black, Red, Pink, Green}, {"Show", "me", "Hello","World"}, 
{{0.2, 0.2}, {0.4, 0.4}, {0.8, 0.8}, {0.9, 0.9}}}]]
```

Although I can group them up and call it liks below, but the legends need to be placed as specified.

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {3, 1, 2, 5}, {5, 2, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 1, 3}}, 
ChartLegends -> {Placed[SwatchLegend[{Black, Red, Pink, Green},
{"Show", "me", "Hello", "World"}], {0.2, 0.2}]}]
```

PlotLegends don't seem to have such issue:

```
ListPlot[{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {3, 1, 2, 5}, {5, 2, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 1, 3}}, 
PlotLegends -> MapThread[Placed[SwatchLegend[{#1}, {#2}], #3] &,
{{Black, Red, Pink, Green}, {"Show", "me", "Hello", "World"}, 
{{0.2, 0.2}, {0.4, 0.4}, {0.8, 0.8}, {0.9, 0.9}}}]]
```

Answer (score 2):

`ChartLegends` and `PlotLegends` have subtle differences, so it is not quite comparing two equivalent things. In this case, though, I think using either in this case is incorrect as you are creating your own legends, completely. I would use `Legended` directly, e.g.

```
Legended[
 BarChart[{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {3, 1, 2, 5}, {5, 2, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 1, 3}}],
 MapThread[Placed[SwatchLegend[{#1}, {#2}], #3] &,
  {{Black, Red, Pink, Green}, {"Show", "me", "Hello","World"}, 
  {{0.2, 0.2}, {0.4, 0.4}, {0.8, 0.8}, {0.9, 0.9}}}]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @rcollyer ! This seems to be the solution, now I have to see how to incorporate this into my actual codes...